Why inner join creates new distinct values in other column?
I make SQL-queries in Hive using Hue. When I use inner join between two tables, one of the table's column get new distinct values, that wasn't in this column before join.
I have table periods with columns period_name and period_first_dt, table  traffic with columns period_first_dt, product_id and traffic_sum. Detailed info about tables below:
Table periods



Column
Data type
Value example




period_name
string
DEC-23


period_first_dt
datetime
2023-12-01 00:00:00



Table traffic



Column
Data type
Value example




period_first_dt
string
2018-01-01T00:00:00Z


product_id
bigint
135


traffic_sum
bigint
123123



I want to have period_name in traffic table and calculate sum of traffic_sum by period_name. I inner join two tables like this:
with periods as ( 
    select 
      period_name, 
      cast(period_first_dt as date) as period_first_dt
    from 
      periods
    where 1=1 
      and period_name in ('NOV-23', 'DEC-23')
    )
select
  p.period_name,
  sum(t.traffic_sum) as traffic_sum  
from  
  traffic t
join
  periods p on p.period_first_dt = cast(substring(t.period_first_dt, 1, 10) as date)
where 1=1
  and t.product_id = 135
group by
  p.period_name
;

CTE periods have following values:



period_name
period_first_dt




DEC-23
2023-12-01


NOV-23
2023-11-01



Query above have following results:



period_name
traffic_sum




2023-11-01
1894758884807.576


2023-12-01
1953671751139.3423


DEC-23
132211702997.26137


NOV-23
90683990757.3648



Column period_name somehow have new values that wasn't before inner join: 2023-11-01 and 2023-12-01. When I change condition in CTE and period_name in ('NOV-23', 'DEC-23') to and period_name = 'DEC-23', results are without new values in period_name:



period_name
traffic_sum




DEC-23
2085883454136.6035



When I remove condition and t.product_id = 135 and leave condition in CTE and period_name in ('NOV-23', 'DEC-23'), results are somehow without new values in period_name:



period_name
traffic_sum




DEC-23
2658701852149.3955


NOV-23
2518165900926.1953



Why new distinct values appear in period_name and how to fix that?

Please ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question. Either ask re 1 bad query/function with obligatory [mre], including why you think it should return something else or are unsure at the 1st subexpression where you don't get what you expect or are stuck, justified by reference to authoritative documentation, or ask about your overall goal giving working parts you can do with justification & a [mre]--then misunderstood code doesn't belong. But please ask about unexpected behaviour 1st because misconceptions get in the way of your goal. [ask] [Help] Basic questions are faqs.

A [mre] includes cut & paste & runnable code including initialization; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization code. For debug that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK.

I am not at all sure but try renaming periods to periodsx.
In your main select statement I am not sure it it fetches your"with data as" table or you actual table periods. If that make sense?
with **periodsx** as ( 
    select 
      period_name, 
      cast(period_first_dt as date) as period_first_dt
    from 
      periods --do not change here
    where 1=1 
      and period_name in ('NOV-23', 'DEC-23')
    )
select
  p.period_name,
  sum(t.traffic_sum) as traffic_sum  
from  
  traffic t
join
  **periodsx** p on p.period_first_dt = cast(substring(t.period_first_dt, 1, 10) as date)
where 1=1
  and t.product_id = 135
group by
  p.period_name
;


unfortunately, it doenst change anything

What does the following result in?
with periodsx as (
select
period_name,
cast(period_first_dt as date) as period_first_dt
from
periods
where 1=1
and period_name in ('NOV-23', 'DEC-23')
)
select *
from  periodsx
